# How to check whether the result of an Ansible task is the same on all the servers?

Tags: ansible

As part of an Ansible playbook, I want to verify whether my servers are in sync.

To do so, I execute a script on each of my servers using the `shell` module and I register the result into a variable, say `result_value`.

The tricky part is to verify whether `result_value` is the same on all the servers. The expected value is not known beforehand.

Is there an idiomatic way to achieve this in Ansible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of possible ways:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - shell: /usr/bin/my_check.sh
      register: result_value
    - assert:
        that: hostvars[item]['result_value'].stdout == result_value.stdout
      with_items: "{{play_hosts}}"
      run_once: true
```

Comment: Won't this run only the first host?

Comment: @RobertoAloi if you use standard run strategy, first `shell` is executed on every host and writes result to `result_value` var of that host, then `assert` is executed on one of the hosts (because of `run_once`), but loops over every host in current play (because of `with_items`) and compares each host result_value to its own.

Comment: As a note, I first got an error using your solution (`ERROR! Can't LOOKUP(dig): module dns.resolver is not installed`) The  `pip install --upgrade dnspython` command helped.